# Using timer capture on Atmega128A

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, atmega

I read the datasheet of Atmega128 and tried using input capture pin ICP1. 
To test it I am generating a sqaure wave on PORTC pin 1. I am using USB-TTL to see the value on my laptop using X-CTU software using the command `USART_Transmitnumber(timer_capt, 0)` and `USART_Transmitchar(0x0d,0)` is for next line command. I have confirmed that USART functions and the square wave on PORTC pin 1 are working fine. The problem is that the value of variable `timer_capt` is never getting printed. That means that no interrupt event is being generated. What am I doing wrong?

```c
int main(void) 
{
    TCNT1 = 0;
    TCCR1B = (1 << ICNC1) | (1<<ICES1) | (1<<CS10);
    sei();

    DDRC = 0x01;
    while (1) {
         PORTC = 0x01;
         _delay_ms(100);
         PORTC = 0;
         _delay_ms(100);
    }
}

ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
{
    timer_capt = TCNT1; 
    USART_TransmitNumber(timer_capt, 0);
    USART_Transmitchar(0x0d,0);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question, and provide a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is unclear what what you are asking about and what your expected result is. You declare the function _ISR_ without a return value and no type for TIMER1_CAPT_vect, and you never call it from _main_, so it won't be executed...

Comment: 1. Did you enable the input capture interrupt by setting bit `TICIE1` in thi `TIMSK` register? 2. Are you sure `USART_Transmit...` works from within an interrupt handler (_i.e._ when further interrupts are disabled)?

Comment: @andpei `ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect){}` correctly defines an interrupt handler for Timer1 Capture events, and _will_ be called on these events if the interrupt is enabled.  (ISR is a macro).